# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Element to Elements & first cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, jquery, parsing, jsoup

I'm attempting to build a HTML parser and I'm getting two errors stating:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Element to Elements  MainActivity.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 55 Java Problem
first cannot be resolved or is not a field  MainActivity.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 54 Java Problem
```

on the lines:

```
Elements th = doc.select("tr").first;
Elements firstTh = th.select("th").first();
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening or what I can do to resolve this issue? It's my first time building a parser so I'm not sure exactly what I've done wrong.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    final String URL = "http://exampleurl.com";
String tr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(URL);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Elements tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid");
                Elements th = doc.select("tr").first;
                Elements firstTh = th.select("th").first();
                title = firstTh.text();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler errors are a good indicator of the issue - [`first`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first%28%29) returns an `Element` object rather than `Elements`

```
Elements th = doc.select("tr").first;
```

should be

```
Element th = doc.select("tr").first();
```

Also replace

```
Elements firstTh = th.select("th").first();
```

with

```
Element firstTh = th.select("th").first();
```

Comment: select does return Elements, it's the first() that returns an Element.